# Ethers.js throws other errors then expected by write function and read function works as expected (solidity custom error)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I am building a smart contract which is deployed to the telos evm test-network. I am using custom errors in my contract for read and write functions.

Read

```
function getMyNumber() public view returns (uint256) {
   if(myNumber == 0) {
      revert NumberNotSet(myNumber);
   }
   return myNumber
}
```

Write

```
function setMyNumber(uint256 number) public {
   if(number > 10) {
      revert NumberToHigh(number);
   }
   myNumber = number;
}
```

If i call the read function from ethers with the following code everything works as expected (i'll receive my custom error with the args)

```
async readContractAction(
    contractAddress: string,
    functionName: string,
    ...args
  ) {
    const contract = await this.getContract(contractAddress);
    if (contract === undefined) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        'No contract with the given address could be found!',
      );
    }
    try {
      return await contract[functionName](...args);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
      throw new BadRequestException(
        `Function responded with an error: ${err.args} - ${err.errorName}`,
      );
    }
  }
```

If I want to call the write method with e.g. 11 as parameter I would expect that I'll receive my created custom error because the given number is to high.
But I get some weird errors `invalid length for gasLimit`, `estimateGas: invalid BigNumber string`, `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`. But If I add the gas limit manually as the error pointed out, I'll get an other error message `Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized`

Ethers.js write action code:

```
async writeContractAction(
    contractAddress: string,
    functionName: string,
    ...args
  ) {
    const contract = await this.getContract(contractAddress);
    if (contract === undefined) {
      throw new NotFoundException(
        'No contract with the given address could be found!',
      );
    }
    try {
      const tx = await contract[functionName](...args);
      await tx.wait();
      console.log('SUCCESS', tx);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
    }
  }
```

If I change the revert statement in the `setMyNumber` function to a require statement like this, I'll get the expected error and the error reason.

```
function setMyNumber(uint256 number) public {
   require(number <= 10, "number to high")
   if(number > 10) {
      revert NumberToHigh(number);
   }
   myNumber = number;
}
```

I don't understand what I'm missing and I was wondering if there is an known pattern to handle such custom errors in ethers.js

EDIT 02/06 --------------

In the example above I used the following rpc url for telos evm test net: https://testnet.telos.net/evm

So my write function `setMyNumber` works absolutely fine until I trigger a revert, for example try to store a number that is greater then 10. For the numbers 0 - 9 everything works as expected. My read `getMyNumber` function works fine in any case. It doesn't matter if I trigger an revert I always get either the number if it is not "0" or my created custom error. So my contract is deployed and I am enter the correct contract address otherwise no function would work but as I said only the write functions throws such errors but only if I trigger a revert.

I also copied my contract in remix and deployed it to different test nets:

- Injected Web3 (Telos evm testnet ) -> write function with revert error throws the mentioned weird errors
- Rinkeby -> reverted correct error as expected